# Why wont the `minted` package produce output?

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a document with code examples using `minted`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{minted}

\title{Modelling stuff}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

    \begin{minted}{python}
        x = 4
    \end{minted}


\end{document}
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and ensured `minted` was installed using `sudo tlmgr install minted`, which seemed to work. I'm compiling this via PyCharm's `texify` plugin. I've also tried pdfLatex and XeLatex compilers. However, when I compile, nothing happens. No error and no output.

Does anybody by any chance know why? Failing that, does anybody have an alternative means of getting Python syntax colouring? (I also need bash)

### Edit

- `Pygments` is already installed

Comment: if you get no output you should get an error, what does the log file say (did you use `pdflatex --shell-escape` to allow it to run external programs?)

Comment: I've just ran `latex --shell-escape file.tex` from the terminal and it worked. Now the question is why won't this work from within `Pycharm's` `texify` plugin?

Comment: Got it. The problem is that latex needs the `--shell-escape` flag, even from `pycharm` otherwise it produces nothing. You can edit the configuration in PyCharm to include this option. Thanks @DavidCarlisle for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minted requires pdflatex to be allowed to run external programs so `pdflatex --shell-escape`  Calling external programs is disabled by default for security reasons.